# Insert of data into MongoDB failed: localhost:27017: cannot use 'j' option

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

Insert of data into MongoDB failed: localhost:27017: cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled in codeigniter with mongodb

**Controller**

maincontroller.php

```
function createUser() {

$this->load->library('mongo_db'); 
$user = array("name" => "tutorialspoint3"); 
$options = array(
   "w" => 1,
   "j" => true,

); 

$this->mongo_db->insert('tutorialspoint', $user,$options); 

}
```

Comment: i have alredy add mongo_db in cofig and libraries. i have enable journal using cmd mongod --journal and mongod c:\data --journal and  mongod c:\data\db --journal

Comment: Sounds like you are using a 32-bit build or an older than MongoDB 2.0 build. Journaling is on by default otherwise. An upgrade or change of environment would be recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem, you are probably using a 32 bit mongod which has journaling disabled by default.

Just start the database with `--journal or add "journal=true"` to your mongod.conf (on debian you can find it in /etc/mongod/) to start the database with journaling enabled